# There has got to be a cleaner way to do this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, multidimensional-array

I have this code [here](http://pastie.org/1209121) and it works but there has to be a better way.....i need two arrays that look like this

```
[ 
{
  "Vector Arena - Auckland Central, New Zealand" => { 
    "2010-10-10" => [
       "Enter Sandman", 
       "Unforgiven", 
       "And justice for all"
    ]
  }
},  
{
  "Brisbane Entertainment Centre - Brisbane Qld, Austr..." => { 
    "2010-10-11" => [
      "Enter Sandman"
    ]
  }
}
]
```

one for the past and one for the upcoming...the problem i have is i am repeating myself and though it works i want to clean it up ...here is my [data](http://pastie.org/1207685)
..

Comment: How is this different from your last question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891231/how-do-i-create-this-multidemsional-array-hash-combo

Comment: its different because i need to break this up now into two arrays and i dont want to duplicate the logic if i can help it

Comment: @KandadaBoggu - also I appreciate your answer to the previous question..thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
h = Hash.new {|h1, k1| h1[k1] = Hash.new{|h2, k2| h2[k2] = []}}
result, today = [ h, h.dup], Date.today

Request.find_all_by_artist("Metallica", 
 :select => "DISTINCT venue, showdate, LOWER(song) AS song"
).each do |req|
  idx = req.showdate < today ? 0 : 1
  result[idx][req.venue][req.showdate] << req.song.titlecase
end
```

**Note 1**

In the first line I am initializing an hash of hashes. The outer hash creates the inner hash when a non existent key is accessed. An excerpt from Ruby Hash [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002840):

```
If this hash is subsequently accessed by a key that doesn‘t correspond to a hash 
entry, the block will be called with the hash object and the key, and should 
return the default value. It is the block‘s responsibility to store the value in 
the hash if required.
```

The inner hash creates and empty array when the non existent date is accessed.

E.g: Construct an hash containing of content as values and date as keys:

Without a default block:

```
h = {}
list.each do |data|
  h[data.date] = [] unless h[data.date]
  h[data.date] << data.content
end
```

With a default block

```
h = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}
list.each do |data|
  h[data.date] << data.content
end
```

Second line simply creates an array with two items to hold the past and future data. Since both past and the present stores the data as Hash of Hash of Array, I simply duplicate the value.

Second line can also be written as

```
result = [ h, h.dup]
today = Date.today
```

Comment: this looks awesome thank you soo much .. though can you explain the first two lines

Comment: i get this though  ActiveRecord::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: song

Comment: Updated my answer take a look.

Comment: thanks alot.....only thing i had to change was the ).each do |req|....you forgot the do

Comment: Updated my answer with explanation. Take a look.